# If I want to use placeholders in continuous query in Apache IoTDB, how should I write the command?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

For continuous query in Apache IoTDB, when I am using `select into ... group by time` command, can this statement support placeholders? If this command do not support placeholders and I want to use placeholders later to switch this part to different values of the inserted data, how should I write this command?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `align by device` to your statement in Apache IoTDB, and then you can use placeholders. Since if you don't add `align by device`, the header of your result set will be something like `count(root.db.d1.s1)`, and the path information cannot be extracted because it has been "wrapped up" by an aggregation function. After adding `align by device`, the path name can be extracted from the device column, so it can be used to replace placeholders.